# Difference between Reused Bases Software engineering and Component Basic Software engineering?

Tags: architecture

same thing in rescued base and component base all reuse component.i can't find any deference between this.

difference between Reused Bases Software Engineering and Component Basic Software Engineering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Reused Bases Software Engineering can be reused not only components but broader set of artifacts.

Component base is more focused on reusing components and artifacts created as components.
Here is comparison table:
[image: comparison table]

Here is good paper on that : http://www.idt.mdh.se/kurser/cdt501/2007/lectures/Managing%20CBSE%20and%20Reuse.pdf